# Как можно переписать рекурсивный поиск количества вершин в дереве?

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм

*> Максимальное число вершин дерева в цепочке, начинающейся в корне дерева, заканчивающейся в одном из его листьев, и не содержащей никакую вершину дважды. При использовании рекурсии вылетает stackoverflowexception.*

```
 public class Node
    {
        public Node left, right;
        public double key;

        public Node(int key)
        {
            this.key = key;
        }
    }
    public class BinaryTree
    {
        public Node root;
        public void Insert(int key)
        {
            Node x = root, y = null;
            double cmp = 0;
            while (x != null)
            {
                cmp = x.key - key;
                if (cmp == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    y = x;
                    if (cmp < 0)
                    {
                        x = x.right;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        x = x.left;
                    }
                }
            }
            Node newNode = new Node(key);
            if (y == null)
            {
                root = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cmp > 0)
                {
                    y.left = newNode;
                }
                else
                {
                    y.right = newNode;
                }
            }
        }

        public static int Height(Node node)// рекурсивный поиск вершин
        {
            if (node == null) return 0;
            return 1 + Math.Max(Height(node.left), Height(node.right));
        }
    }
```

Comment: если вылетает stackoverflowexception, значит либо очень глубокое дерево, либо в дереве есть циклы, по которым ты ходишь бесконечно. Приведи пример дерева на котором ты пробуешь

Comment: Дерево размера 34112, в котором бывают только левые потомки.

Comment: что за размер тут имеется ввиду?

Comment: В дерево заносят числа с 1 по 34112. После чего ищут количество вершин - высоту дерева.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте своё дерево на цикличность

```
public static int Height(Node node, Dictionary<Node, int> memory)// рекурсивный поиск вершин
{       
    if (node == null) return 0;
    if (memory.ContainsKey(node)){
        // У вас цикл. Для дерева такого быть не должно

        // Если вы хотите бросить исключение в этом случае, то
        // throw new Exception("Tree has a cycle!");

        // если всё таки хотите с циклом посчитать, то
        // return memory[node];
    }

    var height = 1 + Math.Max(Height(node.left, memory), Height(node.right, memory));
    memory[node] = height;
    return height;
}
```

Comment: а почему Dictionary а не HashSet?

Comment: @Grundy `если всё таки хотите с циклом посчитать, то  // return memory[node];`